# How to delete package in monodevelop, if it is impossible to restore it?

Tags: nuget, monodevelop, nuget-package-restore

When I am trying to delete a package from the solution tree, monodevelop gives me a message ["Unable to find package " ...  " to remove it from the project. Please restore the package first."](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement.Commands/PackageReferenceNodeCommandHandler.cs#L67)

I am unable to restore package, because NuGet.exe gives an error

"Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)" and then

"Unable to find version 'N.M.K' of package 'SomePackageName'"

How to delete these packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to fix the "SendFailure (Error writing headers)" error if you are on Linux by running:

```
mozroots --import --sync
```

If you cannot find the original NuGet package you can manually remove the package. Currently with the built-in NuGet addin in MonoDevelop you cannot forcefully remove a NuGet package. MonoDevelop uses the NuGet package contents to work out what needs to be removed from the project.

Manual removal will be a case of:

1. Edit the packages.config file and removing the `<package>` element for that package.
2. Edit the project file (.csproj) file and find any references that are from the packages directory (e.g. packages/Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5) for that NuGet package.

Comment: mozroots --import --sync<br />removes some installed certificates